# How to verify that TestDriven.net uses NUnit 2.5.vNext?

Tags: nunit, testdriven.net, nunit-2.5

I go to VS2010, tools, options, TestDriven.Net, Test Runners.

I observe NUnit 2.5 with version 2.5.0 thru 2.5.65535.65535 to be launched.

How do I configure TestDriven.Net to use NUnit 2.5.10, or whatever is the latest and greatest?

EDIT:

I am using TestDriven.Net 3.0 RTM.  Unfortunately, there's no testdriven.net-3 tag here.

My understanding of the issue was incorrect.  TestDriven.Net reports NUnit 2.5.5 as version used to generate test results.  I think it ships and executes with NUnit 2.5.5.  With that said, nunit.mocks.dll and pnunit aren't included in TD.Net distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this, I copied all contents of bin folder under NUnit installation into 2.5 folder under TestDriven.Net installation.  Best way is to make a backup copy of 2.5 folder, since this is somewhat a hack.  I am currently running 2.5.10 release of NUnit from TestDriven.Net:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: XXX.dll ------

15 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 2.05 seconds (NUnit 2.5.10).
```

There are some additional dlls within 2.5 folder that TestDriven.Net relies on, but they are retained if the mentioned procedure is followed carefully.